# changing a query result value according to wherehas condition in laravel

Tags: laravel, iteration

I am using laravel

I want to change the value of a column according to a specific condition.
if a condition is satisfied in wherehas then change the value of specific column to 1 let's say.How could i do it.
if i can call a function in the model inside the wherehas function to change the value how could I do it ??

i can iterate the result set using a 2 for loops and change it, however I want to decrease the complexity by changing the value while retrieving the data

```html
Course::with('stages','stages.levels')->whereHas('stages.levels', function($query)use ($levelsarray){
            $query->wherenotIn('id', $levelsarray);
            here I want to change a column value in table levels
        })->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general way,

Assuming you have Three models, **Course, Stage, Level**
When you are retrieving data from **Level** model, add an accessor,
For more info [click here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators).

Eg:

On `Level.php` model,

```
public function getColumnNameAttribute($value) // replace ColumnName with column name
{
    //write application logic here.

    return $value;
}
```

Comment: I want to change the value according to an array defined in my controller, so if the id exist in the array then value should be 0 otherwise value is 1 .